# Error: Could not find or load main class files\kafka_2.12-2.4.0\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;

Tags: apache-kafka

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   files\kafka_2.12-2.4.0\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;

Comment: What command did you run? What version of Kafka did you get? What is your host OS? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would appear you may have put Kafka in "Program files" directory.

On windows, the kafka path cannot contain spaces. Try c:\kafka

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to check JAVA_HOME, whether java installed & correct classpath or not
2. Zookeeper path need to check, especially folder name should not have spaces.
   eg: Program Files--> use folder like zookeeper or any Program_Files
3. Better to place kafka and zookeeper server folders in C drive not in Program
   Files folder
4. Before run zookeeper command, 1st set javahome path on cmd
   C:\kafka\bin\windows>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
5. Then run the zookeepr cmd
   C:\kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties

100% it will work. I did not get any where this answer that I searched. After I trouble shooted for 3 hours I got resolved this issue. It will work.